# Return the characters after Nth character in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I need help! Can someone please let me know how to return the characters after the nth character?

For example, the strings I have is "001 baseball" and "002 golf", I want my code to return baseball and golf, not the number part. Since the word after the number is not always the same length, I cannot use  = Right(String, n)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why can't you use Right(String, n)?

Answer (score 19):

If your numbers are always 4 digits long:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-5) //'0001 Baseball' returns Baseball
```

If the numbers are variable (i.e. could be more or less than 4 digits) then:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1)) //'123456 Baseball’ returns Baseball
```

Answer (score 9):

`Mid(strYourString, 4)` (i.e. without the optional length argument) will return the substring starting from the 4th character and going to the end of the string.

Comment: In Office 2016 it says, "You've entered too few arguments for this function."  Apparently the length argument is now required.

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, you could do a Text to Columns with space as the delimiter.

Comment: + 1 Best answer in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is the [vba] tag, split is also easy:

```
str1 = "001 baseball"
str2 = Split(str1)
```

Then use str2(1).

Comment: Of course using Split without a delimiter is the same as having a space (" ") as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Another formula option is to use REPLACE function to replace the first n characters with nothing, e.g. if n = 4

`=REPLACE(A1,1,4,"")`