# Loop through column in Excel and add unique string to array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to write a program in VBA at the moment which is to be run in Excel. I am quite stuck right now because I am not very familiar with VBA and doing a search doesn't come up with my specific problem.

I have a column in Excel which has 20,000+ hostnames for PC's on our network. What I need to do is be able to start at A2 and get the data in that cell, parse out the 5th and 6th characters only and check if those two characters are in an array called VariantDepartments. If the characters are in the array, I need to move to A3 and do it again. If the characters are not in the array, I need to add them to the end of the VariantDepartments array and then add those two characters plus the word "Workbook" to another array called DepartmentWorkBookNames at which point I index both arrays +1 and move to A3.

This is what I am working on right now and it does not work:

```
Sub VulnerabilityMacroFinal()
Dim VariantDepartments As Variant
Dim departments As Variant
Dim Department As String
Dim VariantAssetTypes As Variant
Dim AssetTypes As Variant
Dim AssetType As String
Dim Property As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim PropArray() As String
Dim strFile As String  

'Opening file & getting property name
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
If strFile <> "False" Then Workbooks.Open strFile
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
PropArray = Split(FileName, "-")
Property = PropArray(0)

'Setting asset types
VariantAssetTypes = Array("PC", "Server", "Other Assets")

'Program Start
Sheets("AllVulnerabilities").Select

'sorting out unnecessary types
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
"01-Adobe", "02-Apache", "06-Chrome", "09-Firefox", "13-Java", "16-Microsoft", _
"38-VNC"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Selecting the whole sheet
Cells.Select
'Creating sheets for different asset types
For Each AssetTypes In VariantAssetTypes
'Making variable a C String to make it easier to check in If statements
AssetType = CStr(AssetTypes)
    If AssetType = "PC" Then
        'Parsing out the non local PC assets
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Property & "D*"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E,F:F").AutoFilter Field:=1
    ElseIf AssetType = "Server" Then
        'Selecting original sheet
        Sheets("AllVulnerabilities").Select
        'Parsing out the non local Server assets
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Property & "*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>" & Property & "D*"
    ElseIf AssetType = "Other Assets" Then
        'Selecting original sheet
        Sheets("AllVulnerabilities").Select
        'Parsing out the non local Server assets
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & Property & "*"
    End If
    'Copying all info on sheet
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    'Selecting new sheet
    Sheets.Add.Name = Property & " " & AssetType
    'Selecting new sheet
    Sheets(Property & " " & AssetType).Select
    'Pasting data to new sheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'Removing unnecessary colums
    Range("A:A,B:B,D:D,G:G,H:H,J:J,K:K").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    'Auto adjusting column widths
    Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E,F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Property & " " & AssetType).Copy
    'Close Workbook withoutsaving
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next AssetTypes

Sheets(Property & " PC").Select
'THIS IS WHERE THE ARRAY SHOULD BE CREATED.

For Each departments In VariantDepartments
Department = CStr(departments)
    Sheets(Property & " PC").Select
    'Parsing out the non local assets for EH
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Property & "D" & Department & "*"
    'Copying all info on sheet
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    'Selecting new sheet
    Sheets.Add.Name = Property & Department
    'Selecting new sheet
    Sheets(Property & Department).Select
    'Pasting data to new sheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'Auto adjusting column widths
    Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E,F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Property & Department).Copy
    'Close Workbook withoutsaving
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    'Set PC Worksheet to be unfiltered
    Worksheets(Property & " PC").ShowAllData
Next departments
   'Completed
   ActiveWindow.Close savechanges:=False
'Message box which appears when everything is done
MsgBox "Done!"
```

End Sub

Comment: These are some really basic array issues. I am sure you can find the answers yourself, but perhaps you are not familiar with the terms that would result in the answers you are looking for. First of all you want to use a FOR loop to move through you column A, and within that another FOR loop to move through your Array. Then you would need two IF statements, one in case you found a match, and one in case you did not. I hope this can help you get started. Also if you already produced some code it would be nice to share it, so that we can see were you went wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256786/looping-through-an-array-in-excel-vba this link could be of help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878151/return-the-characters-after-nth-charater-in-a-string helpful on how to take certain numbers from a string

Comment: I added what I have that doesn't work.  By doing a nested for loop, this would take a lot of time considering it would need to loop through the array 20,000+ times.  If I could do this in Java, life would be a lot easier since they have this built in to the mutable arrays. However I have never had success integrating Java into Excel. The idea is to move this to a batch file or something like that after I finish the macro.

Comment: I have added my whole file and where I need to add the dictionary portion. I also changed a few things so that I do not need the second array (DepartmentWorkBookNames) any longer. All I need to do is create the department array now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those wondering, this is my completed macro, everything works 100% and from input to completion is 20-60 seconds.

```
Sub VulnerabilityMacroFinal()
Dim VariantDepartments As Variant
Dim departments As Variant
Dim Department As String
Dim VariantAssetTypes As Variant
Dim AssetTypes As Variant
Dim AssetType As String
Dim Property As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim PropArray() As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim i As Long


'Opening file & getting property name
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
If strFile <> "False" Then Workbooks.Open strFile
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
PropArray = Split(FileName, "-")
Property = PropArray(0)

'Setting asset types
VariantAssetTypes = Array("PC", "Server", "Other Assets")

'Program Start
Sheets("AllVulnerabilities").Select

'sorting out unnecessary types
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
"01-Adobe", "02-Apache", "06-Chrome", "09-Firefox", "13-Java", "16-Microsoft", _
"38-VNC"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

'Saving sorted workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="\\" & Property & "\shared\IT\PC Remediation\" & Property & "_Remediation_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Selecting the whole sheet
Cells.Select
'Creating sheets for different asset types
For Each AssetTypes In VariantAssetTypes
'Making variable a C String to make it easier to check in If statements
AssetType = CStr(AssetTypes)
    If AssetType = "PC" Then
        'Parsing out the non local PC assets
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Property & "D*"
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E,F:F").AutoFilter Field:=1
    ElseIf AssetType = "Server" Then
        'Selecting original sheet
        Sheets("AllVulnerabilities").Select
        'Parsing out the non local Server assets
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Property & "*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>" & Property & "D*"
    ElseIf AssetType = "Other Assets" Then
        'Selecting original sheet
        Sheets("AllVulnerabilities").Select
        'Parsing out the non local Server assets
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & Property & "*"
    End If
    'Copying all info on sheet
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    'Selecting new sheet
    Sheets.Add.Name = Property & " " & AssetType
    'Selecting new sheet
    Sheets(Property & " " & AssetType).Select
    'Pasting data to new sheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'Removing unnecessary colums
    Range("A:A,B:B,D:D,G:G,H:H,J:J,K:K").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    'Auto adjusting column widths
    Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E,F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Property & " " & AssetType).Copy
    'Saving new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="\\" & Property & "\shared\IT\PC Remediation\" & Property & AssetType & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    'Close Workbook withoutsaving
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next AssetTypes

Sheets(Property & " PC").Select
AddDepartments VariantDepartments
For Each departments In VariantDepartments
Department = CStr(departments)
    Sheets(Property & " PC").Select
    'Parsing out the non local assets for EH
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Property & "D" & Department & "*"
    'Copying all info on sheet
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    'Selecting new sheet
    Sheets.Add.Name = Property & Department
    'Selecting new sheet
    Sheets(Property & Department).Select
    'Pasting data to new sheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'Auto adjusting column widths
    Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E,F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Property & Department).Copy
    'Saving new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="\\" & Property & "\shared\IT\PC Remediation\" & Property & Department & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    'Close Workbook withoutsaving
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    'Set PC Worksheet to be unfiltered
    Worksheets(Property & " PC").ShowAllData
Next departments
   'Completed
   ActiveWindow.Close savechanges:=False
'Message box which appears when everything is done
MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
'Function checks if value exists in collection
Public Function Exists(ByVal oCol As Collection, ByVal vKey As Variant) As     Boolean

On Error Resume Next
oCol.Item vKey
Exists = (Err.Number = 0)
Err.Clear

End Function

Sub AddDepartments(VDepts As Variant)
Dim newDepartments As New Collection, a
Dim i As Long, m As Long, n As Long
Dim code As String

'Getting A column info
n = Range("A:A").Rows.Count
n = Cells(n, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Creating the Collection with all the Departments
For i = 2 To n
    'Getting cell value in Column A (Hostname)
    code = Cells(i, "A").Value
    'Getting department code from Hostname
    code = Mid(code, 5, 2)
    'Checking collection to see if it exists
    If Not Exists(newDepartments, code) Then newDepartments.Add code, code
Next i
n = newDepartments.Count
'Moving everything from collection to variant array
If n > 0 Then
    If IsArray(VDepts) Then
        m = UBound(VDepts)
        ReDim Preserve VDepts(LBound(VDepts) To m + n)
    Else
        m = 0
        ReDim VDepts(1 To n)
    End If
    For i = 1 To n
        VDepts(m + i) = newDepartments(i)
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

20,000+ linear searches could slow your application to a crawl. It is a better idea to create a dictionary to store the codes. You can load the codes to a dictionary, iterate through column A grabbing any new department codes, then tack the newly discovered codes on the ends of the arrays. To use a dictionary, you need to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your projects (tools/references in the VBA editor). The following functions and subs should be easily modifiable for your purposes. I am assuming that `VariantDepartment` and `DepartmentWorkBookNames` are declared as simple Variant variables (and not as arrays of variants) and that when the main sub is invoked they are either empty or hold 1-dimensional arrays. If they are empty, they are dimensioned to be arrays large enough to hold the codes. In this case, *they are 1-based* meaning that their indexing starts at 1. The code would have to be modified slightly to make them 0-based. To test it, I created a small amount of dummy data in column A and checked that the two arrays were updated appropriately:

```
Function DictFromArray(items As Variant) As Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    Dim d As New Dictionary
    If Not IsArray(items) Then
        Set DictFromArray = d 'empty dictionary
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = LBound(items) To UBound(items)
        If Not d.Exists(items(i)) Then
            d.Add items(i), ""
        End If
    Next i
    Set DictFromArray = d
End Function

Sub AddDepartments(VDepts As Variant, DNames As Variant)
    Dim departments As Dictionary
    Dim newDepartments As New Collection
    Dim i As Long, m As Long, k As Long, n As Long
    Dim code As String

    Set departments = DictFromArray(VDepts)
    n = Range("A:A").Rows.Count
    n = Cells(n, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To n
        code = Cells(i, "A").Value
        code = Mid(code, 5, 2)
        If Not departments.Exists(code) Then newDepartments.Add code
    Next i
    n = newDepartments.Count
    If n > 0 Then
        If IsArray(VDepts) Then
            m = UBound(VDepts)
            ReDim Preserve VDepts(LBound(VDepts) To m + n)
        Else
            m = 0
            ReDim VDepts(1 To n)
        End If
        If IsArray(DNames) Then
            k = UBound(DNames)
            ReDim Preserve DNames(LBound(DNames) To k + n)
        Else
            k = 0
            ReDim DNames(1 To n)
        End If
        For i = 1 To n
            VDepts(m + i) = newDepartments(i)
            DNames(k + i) = newDepartments(i) & "Workbook"
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim VariantDepartment As Variant
    Dim DepartmentWorkBookNames As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    VariantDepartment = Array("CD", "FX")
    DepartmentWorkBookNames = Array("CDWorkbook", "FXWorkbook")
    AddDepartments VariantDepartment, DepartmentWorkBookNames
    For i = LBound(VariantDepartment) To UBound(VariantDepartment)
        Debug.Print VariantDepartment(i)
    Next i
    For i = LBound(DepartmentWorkBookNames) To UBound(DepartmentWorkBookNames)
        Debug.Print DepartmentWorkBookNames(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Output:

```
CD
FX
AB
FF
GG
GH
CDWorkbook
FXWorkbook
ABWorkbook
FFWorkbook
GGWorkbook
GHWorkbook
```

The last 4 values in each array correspond to the new values in the 5th and 6th positions in the entries in column A. You can comment out the two lines in which the variants are assigned arrays using the Array() function and verify that it succeeds in populating those two variables correctly.

Comment: When I get into the Function, I get a Subscript out of range in the For i = LBound(items) To UBound(items) part. In the main script I put the AddDepartments VariantDepartment, DepartmentWorkBookNames only

Comment: @ZOMGnerd You must be passing that function a 2-dimensional array. Is VariantDepartment grabbed from a column in a spreadsheet by a simple assignment (something like `VariantDepartment = Range("whatever").Value`)? If so -- VBA oddly enough will interpret VariantDepartment as a 2-dimensional array with only 1 column. There are some fixes, but not easy to describe in the comments.

Comment: I didn't set the value for the array. I just have it as Dim VariantDepartments() As Variant. I tried setting it to 50 and it went past that error but then I get another one saying that the array is fixed when I try to ReDim Preserve.

Comment: Try Dim VariantDepartments as Variant. Note the absence of parenthesis. One of the subtle things about VBA -- variants which hold arrays are much more flexible than arrays of variants. At some stage you need to put values in it. At that stage you use a redim statement to get its initial size (then later Redim preserve if you want to make it even larger).

Comment: Run-time error 13 Type mismatch on the LBound and UBound

Comment: My guess is that you are calling the sub with 1 or both of these arrays initially empty. My mental model is that you had non-empty existing arrays which were expanding. I will modify the code so it can handle empty variants.

Comment: Would it be easier to do a for each loop on the collection to iterate it instead of doing a dictionary to a collection to an array and then iterating the array?

Comment: I was responding to your initial post in which you were checking 20K+ entries against an array that already existed. Dictionaries give a way to avoid the resulting linear search. The point of the collection is that they can grow dynamically without redim preserve at each stage (an expensive operation.) Collections don't have an `exists` method so they aren't nice for membership checking (it would require error trapping). It seems round-about, but the approach I outlined seems to be the best way to get O(1) checks and dynamic arrays. The speed should be good. You could always time it.

Comment: I have added my whole file and where I need to add the dictionary portion. I also changed a few things so that I do not need the second array (DepartmentWorkBookNames) any longer. All I need to do is create the department array now

Comment: This works for the most part however     If Not departments.Exists(code) Then newDepartments.Add code  Does not work